# Magento 1.9.3.10 doesn't place order

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I've some problem with magento 1.9.3.10,
I activated all the errors view but I'm not able to understand why it doesn't place order, it is stucked at step 6 of checkout and at step 2 if I activate some errors views.
That's the [site](https://www.pink-shower.com/shop.html).

Answer (score 0):

You server runs on PHP 7.3.9, Magento 1.9.3.10 is only compatible up to PHP 5.6 out of the box. PHP compatibility to PHP 7.1 and 7.2 is included in Magento 1.9.4.0 or higher. So a simple core update would help here – but this won't make the shop compatible to PHP 7.3, only up to PHP 7.2.

I would try to downgrade your PHP version and update your shop first and see if the errors still appear.

Comment: I've downgraded php version to 5.6 and the problem is the same. Is there any way to activate some other errors view?

Comment: Network analysis in the browser still shows that you use PHP 7.3.9 in the webshop.

Comment: omg you're right. How is it possible? I really made the downgrade to 5.6.

Comment: With php 5.6 (I'm sure now) onepage checkout is totally blank.

Comment: Blank checkout was due to mcrypt lack. I fixed that but checkout doesn't place order. I really don't know where to search errors :-(

Comment: Browse the shop and place an error while at the same time you monitor your apache error log at the same time, using your command line interface on your server: `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log`
The output may show you error messages which can help you, other magento specific logs can be found in `/magento/var/log/system.log` and `/magento/var/log/exception.log`

Comment: Really thanks. From magento log i didn't find anything interesting but in httpd log I have a very persistent error: PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'mcrypt_compat/mcrypt.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/xxx/httpsdocs/app/code/local:/var/www/html/xxx/httpsdocs/app/code/community:/var/www/html/xxx/httpsdocs/app/code/core:/var/www/html/xxx/httpsdocs/lib:.:/opt/remi/php56/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/remi/php56/root/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/xxx/httpsdocs/app/Mage.php on line 60, referer: https://www.xxx/checkout/onepage/